How to query Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint from Python with user-specific credentials to test performance based on graph permissions?
I am running Virtuoso on a Docker container on localhost:8890. My goal is to test whether adding permissions/restrictions to certain graphs results in time inefficiencies when querying. For this reason, through Virtuoso Conductor, I have created users, other than the dba, with different permissions regarding access to the graphs/ontologies I have loaded. Through the ISQL interface on Virtuoso Conductor (localhost:8890/conductor/isql.vspx), it is possible to run queries by choosing which user is executing it directly from the interface, but there is no way to estimate the response time. Additionally, I would like to do this by querying the endpoint from Python, for example.
For now, I have written this code that queries the SPARQL endpoint (localhost:8890/sparql) and returns the correct results but executes as the default dba (I believe), and I have not found any working way to specify which user is executing the query:
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, CSV

sparql = SPARQLWrapper('http://localhost:8890/sparql')
sparql.setQuery('''
PREFIX sem:<http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/TravelApp_Ontology#>
SELECT * WHERE {?s a sem:Skiing}
''')
sparql.setReturnFormat(CSV)
qres = sparql.query().convert().decode('utf-8')

print(qres)

Among others, I also tried
sparql = SPARQLWrapper('http://username:password@localhost:8890/sparql'), but it doesn't work. Do you know of a way to execute queries from Python to Virtuoso, specifying which user is executing it, or any other way that could work? Thanks in advance!

I think you'll find your answer in this related question...

@TallTed thank you! I followed the instructions at https://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtSPARQLProtectSQLDigestAuthentication and used the code from the related question and it worked.

Does this answer your question? SPARQLWrapper HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized [pointless new comment added by SO when I said this question should be closed as a duplicate of the other which has already been confirmed to answer the question...]

Answered by SPARQLWrapper HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized. [equally pointless new comment, which SO made by converting what I posted as the answer, after the comments above...]
